# jQuery ajax post Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery ajax.
I have javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('body').on("click", "#pager a", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var a = $(this);
            var model = $('#searchForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Product/Products',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    model: model, page: a
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                    $('#productsList').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code produce error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and I don't understand why. I have no trigger, I used preventDefault and stopPropagation, but I still have this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's really weird. I don't see any reason at all why this code should produce that. Don't you have _any_ other code anywhere else?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your HTML please ? To help us reproduce the error.

Comment: You have `page: a` as part of the data you are submitting, where `a` is a jQuery object - what do you expect that to do?

Comment: How many `<a>`'s are on the page (nested within `#pager`, that is)? Post your html. `#pager` sounds like a *pagination* of sorts. If you, for example, have thousands of *pages* in your pagination display (Eg. ?page=1, ?page=2, 50, 100, 1000), all referenced with `<div id="#pager"><a href="?page=2">...<a href="?page=10000"></div>`, then binding the click handler on ~x `<a>` elements could easily fill the stack.

Answer (score 81):

This error can also come if you are passing something in data which is not defined in that scope.
Another reason is passing in data with val() directly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm passing data with .val() directly but in one property I forgot add .val(), your comment saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed for the `.val()`

Comment: overlooking `.val()` when in a rush to develop code .. great catch.

Comment: I forgot to add the `.value` to the data `textElement`, now it works. So I did `textElement` then I got this error, but when I did `textElement.value` the error is gone.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using var a = $(this) to get the page, use one hidden field and give page value to the field.

```
<input type="hidden" value="xyzpage" id="pageValue">

var pageVal = $("#pageValue").val();

data: {
         model: model, page:pageVal 
      },
```

This will solve the issue I guess

Answer (score 5):

I want to share my experience,

in my case, it was only a wrong parameter name and exactly the same error message :
instead of confID, I put the configID and got this error.

```
 function openNameEditor() {
    var confID = $("#configStatusList").attr("data-id");
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetModelNameToChange", "Admin")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "HTML",
        data: { configID: configID},//Here, instead of confID, I put configID which doesn't exist in the function.
        success: function (response) {
            $("#name-editor").html(response);
        },
        error: function (er) {
            alert(er.error);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take off the `var a = $(this);`. I don't know what you try to achieve there but using a the jQuery wrapped clicked element as request data is a non-sense.

Comment: *"using the event context (represented by this) as a jQuery selector"* - But `this` is *not* the event, it's a reference to the element that the event happened to.

Comment: Yes you're true, my bad. But still trying to send a jQuery wrapped element as request data is strange.

Comment: It's strange, granted, but that's probably unrelated to the `maximum call stack` error.

Comment: I tested in a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/oLLKER?editors=1011) and apparently you're right. For some reason, sending a jQuery object in an ajax call makes it go haywire. Anyway, you're right too when you say that sending a whole jQuery object wherever doesn't make any sense, because it just doesn't :)

Answer (score 0):

Endless loop can also cause this kind of error. View  that you don't call same function inside function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into such a problem when parsing a large piece of JSON using jquery.tmpl.js. This error appears when handling large arrays with the concat() function. Here is a link to the problem: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103583
The problem has not been solved since 2011. To solve it, I had to edit the jquery-3.3.1.js javascript library file. For those who want to repeat this decision, do the following: find the following line in the library file `return concat.apply ([], ret);` and replace it with the code below.

```
        // Flatten any nested arrays
        if ([].flat) return ret.flat();


        var ret2 = [];

        ret.forEach(function (i) {

            if (i instanceof Array) {

                i.forEach(function (i2) {
                    ret2.push(i2);
                });

            } else {
                ret2.push(i);
            }

        });

        return ret2;

        // original code:
        // return concat.apply([], ret);
        // chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103583
```

We check if there is a flat() function in the browser's arsenal, for example, it has a chrome browser, and if there is - simply merge the data arrays - nothing more is needed. If not, the browser will go a slower path, but at least there will be no error.